# Returning count of child in json.rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I have a `Location` model that I render in json format using Rabl. My index.json.rabl looks that way :

```
object false
collection @locations

attributes :id, :name, :address, :rating
```

:rating is an integer calculated from records in the `Rating` model (a `Location` `has_many` `Rating`, a `Rating` `belongs_to` a `Location`). 
But now I would like to retrieve also in the Rabl file the number of line of the `Rating` model used to calculate this value.

I tried :

```
child :ratings do
    attributes :count
end
```

and

```
node(:ratings_count) { |m| @ratings.count }
```

But obviously it doesn't work... Could anyone help me there ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have an attribute count in model rating? I'm sure child(:YOUR_HAS_MANY_ASSOC){attributes :YOUR_ATTRIBUTE} works correctly.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to manually add a count attribute in Rating ? Can't I just use .count on the ratings collection of a Location somehow ? Thanks !

Comment: You mean that you want to use ratings.count in rabl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand what you mean. I think you want to use rating.count in rabl.

You have closed to the answer using "node".

```
node(:ratings_count) { |l| l.ratings.count }
```

In the block of node, local variable "l" is one object of the collection above.

Comment: Excellent, it works great ! I was close, I don't why I didn't think of that... I am still learning Rails, I still have to understand the logic, thanks a lot!!